# Unable to login to Suse 12 SP1 vnc server as root, works as normal user

Tags: root, vnc, sles

I have a Suse 12 SP1 server. I'm not able to login to the vnc service as root, however it works as a normal user. Log entries below are from root attempt. Timestamp and server name removed for brevity. It's a fresh install. Vnc works fine out of the box for root on the Suse 11 servers and also on a different Suse 12 SP1 server. Any suggestions on where I can look for this issue?

```
xinetd[1538]: START: vnc1 from=10.0.0.16
Xvnc[16705]: vncext: VNC extension running!
Xvnc[16705]: vncext: created VNC server for screen 0
Xvnc[16705]: Connections: accepted: 10.0.0.16::54506
Xvnc[16705]: vncext: added inetd sock
Xvnc[16705]: SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.8
Xvnc[16705]: SConnection: Client requests security type None(1)
Xvnc[16705]: VNCSConnST: Server default pixel format depth 24 (32bpp) little-endian rgb888
dbus[971]: [system] Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.12" (uid=0 pid=1639 comm="/usr/sbin/gdm ") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.842" (uid=0 pid=16707 comm="/usr/lib/gdm/gdm-simple-slave --display-id /org/gn")
Xvnc[16705]: VNCSConnST: Client pixel format depth 6 (8bpp) rgb222
gdm-launch-environment]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0)
org.a11y.Bus[16726]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
org.a11y.Bus[16726]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
org.a11y.atspi.Registry[16733]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
org.a11y.atspi.Registry[16733]: Xlib:  extension "XEVIE" missing on display "::1:2".
dbus[971]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.locale1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.locale1.service'
dbus[971]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.locale1'
polkitd[1714]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c27 (system bus name :1.849 [gnome-shell --mode=gdm], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user root by (unknown)(uid=0)
ca.desrt.dconf[16726]: g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
org.a11y.atspi.Registry[16733]: g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
org.a11y.Bus[16726]: g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
gdm-launch-environment]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session closed for user gdm
gdm-launch-environment]: pam_systemd(gdm-launch-environment:session): Failed to release session: Interrupted system call
polkitd[1714]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c27 (system bus name :1.849, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
display-manager[1588]: Failed to remove slave program access to the display. Trying to proceed.
gnome-session[16794]: WARNING: Failed to acquire org.gnome.SessionManager
gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session closed for user root
display-manager[1588]: GLib-GObject: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
display-manager[1588]: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
xinetd[1538]: EXIT: vnc1 status=0 duration=12(sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case

```
rcxdm restart
```

fixed the issue.